# Div responsivo con lista, imágen y botón

Tags: html, css

quisiera conseguir un div responsivo con una lista e imagen al lado, que al cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla la imagen cambie hacia el último lugar. Sinceramente no se como hacer que esto ocurra

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO] por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo pero la que mas me gusta es la siguiente utilizando flexbox

```
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Luego agrega las clases a tu etiquetas html ejemplo

```
<div class='flex-wrapper'>
 <ul>
  <li>pera</li>
  <li>manzana</li>
 </ul>
 
 <img>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder!
realmente lo que deseo hacer se asemeja más a esto:
Adjunto el sitio web de donde tome el ejemplo:
https://www.raymondterrero.com/home1 No he podido hacerlo funcionar con el ejemplo ya que la imagen queda todo el tiempo al lado de la lista :(
[![Así se ve en pantallas grandes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YsRl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YsRl.png) [![Y así en la versión de móviles tablets ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf0F1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf0F1.png)

Comment: Puedes intentar aumentando el max-width del media querie tal vez tu quieras aplicarlo a partir de mas resolucion, pero si funciona

Comment: Hola, se agradece la respuesta, sin embargo recomendamos no responder preguntas de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer]